# Get instance of Class<T> [Runtime-Type Token]

Tags: java, generics

I create a Preferences class and for the Getters I wan't to use Runtime-Type Token.

So here is my getter method:

```
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    // do some crazy stuff (e.g. Double <-> Float)
}
```

Up to that, everything works fine. But I would like that the class parameter will be optional.

```
boolean b = preferences.get(key);
```

So I add an additional method:

```
public <T> T get(String key) {
    // return get(key, Class<T>);
}
```

**Now the Question:** Is there a way to do that? Is there a way to get an/the instance of `Class<T>`.

**It's possible with a small workaround:**

```
public <T> T get(String key, T... args) {
    return get(key, (Class<T>) args.getClass().getComponentType());
}

public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    System.out.println("key  : " + key);
    System.out.println("clazz: " + clazz);
}

// using
Boolean b = get("mykey");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with a small workaround.

```
public <T> T get(String key, T... args) {
    return get(key, (Class<T>) args.getClass().getComponentType());
}

public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    System.out.println("key  : " + key);
    System.out.println("clazz: " + clazz);
}

// using
Boolean b = get("mykey");
```

Jep I don't like the varargs too, but it works so far.

Comment: Try not to copy and paste the same answer to multiple questions - if the questions themselves are the same, consider flagging them as duplicates instead. I've undeleted this answer since you've removed your other one.

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, I accidentally posted my answer in that other question. I **immediately deleted** that one and posted it here. So my answer never exist twice. [JFYI]

Comment: Ah, I see. Sometimes the system gets picky about pasted answers. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. But if you want to class parameter to be optional, simply pass `null` and check if it's not null when you use it.

If you want to infer it from the left-hand side - it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. The generic type information is stored in the calling method, the compiled `T get(String key)` itself only knows that it is generic but has no way to find out which concrete type was used to call it.

```
//code
public <T> T get(String key)
//calling code
Integer value = get("value");

//once compiled 
public Object get(String key)
//calling code
Integer value = (Integer) get("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have this kind of code:

```
Integer i = getPref("integer");
System.out.println(i);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> T getPref(String x) {
  return (T)properties.get(x);
}
```

Here, the type `<T>` is indeed inferred from the left-hand side. Keep in mind that this only amounts to helping you avoid an explicit downcast to `Integer` -- for me personally that's enough and I often use such beasts. Another point to be aware of is that Java's type inference is quite lame and you won't be able to have a call to `getPref` as an argument to another method and have the argument type inferred.

Comment: So the preferenes of the App will become System preferences! And it do not solve the problem. You can not cast a Integer into a Double!

Comment: @MarcelJaeschke What does it matter if I use system prefs as an example? It's clearer than putting an undeclared variable `preferences` in the code. And nothing can save you from a class cast exception if you access the wrong type of preference.

Comment: And when inferring fails you can use `<Integer>getPref("foo")` instead of making an additional method for `getPref("foo", Integer.class)`

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom ... which, in this scenario, is unfortunately just a WTF-inducing way to write `(Integer)getPref("foo")` :) BTW you'll actually have to add the class qualifier before that `<Integer>`, it can't stand alone like that.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik It seems to me that you recommend me to use System.getProperties(). And don't take this personally, but it's not clearer. The question was about generics not about preferences.

And according to the cast exception. Knowing to prevent cast exception helps. But such a workaround depends on `Class<T>`.

Comment: @MarcelJaeschke There, changed the code to your liking. But you just stated **my point**: this is not about preferences, so you should ignore that aspect. I used them because that code compiled as legal Java in my IDE. This code doesn't.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik ahh okay, that makes sense (run in IDE) :-)

Comment: @MarcelJaeschke Yes, with time one gets into the habit of testing one's code through Eclipse (or whatever) before posting. Helps to keep  the quality of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but...

Rather than overloading through generics, consider this pattern:

```
public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
    // boolean impl here
}

public float getFloat(String key) {
    // float impl here
}

// etc
```

Not only is it easier to code but easier to use too - at least you know what types are acceptable.
With your current code, this would compile:

```
SomeUnsupportedClass x = preferences.get("foo", SomeUnsupportedClass.class);
```

but it would explode at runtime because you have not got code to support it.

By the way, that's bad: You want to catch problems at coding time, not runtime.

Comment: I think getWhatever() is exactly the opposite what you are mentioned.

BTW: when you will get an error if you use getBoolean(key){return (boolean) map.get(key)} and the value is a String?

Comment: At runtime, but you'll get an exception of a type mismatch no matter what code pattern you use. But when you know the type, you can do this `if (!(value instanceof Boolean)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value for '" + key + ' is not a boolean, but is a " + value.getClass());` or similar to gives more info, or just return `null` without exploding if you want.

Comment: Undeserved downvote, this is a perfectly valid answer. My objection would be that it's too much boilerplate for just a tiny benefit.

Comment: That's what i'm doing. Additional to that I have some workarounds to emulate casts (which works). But to doing so I need Class<T>.

@Marko Topolnik For my domain it's makes sense! I use already this class in several Apps and save a lot of code (before that I used java.util.Properties)! No more hard cast, parsing and object initialization with every call. And before you ask. It's more like an immutable map. So when you build an instance of my preferences you define which type every key will accept. ...